# Shape files do not show on a Cartopy basemap?

Tags: python, shapefile, cartopy

I am trying to add a few shape files to a Cartopy basemap. It turns out that some shape files work, while the others doesn't. I have googled for the whole day without any luck. Can you please help. 
Below is the code I am using. The two shape files can be downloaded here:

## https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2lp93uz28rmyfcs/AAAiA-p4ge5KzHDC5dXlflXga?dl=0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io.img_tiles import OSM
from cartopy.io import shapereader

#%% ======== map paramters =================
map_extent_eastings=(378000,390000)
map_extent_northings=(6427500,6443000)

#%%
plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.epsg(28350))
ax.set_extent([map_extent_eastings[0],map_extent_eastings[1],map_extent_northings[0],map_extent_northings[1]],crs=ccrs.epsg(28350))

tiler = OSM() 
cur_CRS = tiler.crs
zoom = 8 #12 for the final 
ax.add_image(tiler, zoom, interpolation='bilinear' )


#============= Figure out why this deosn't work ===================
### this one doesn't work 
ax.add_geometries(shapereader.Reader('data/AdditionalPumping_south_v2_test.shp').geometries(), 
                  ccrs.epsg(28350),facecolor='none',edgecolor='r',linewidth=1.5,zorder=10)

# This one works 
ax.add_geometries(shapereader.Reader('data/MAR_locations_v2.shp').geometries(), 
                  ccrs.epsg(28350),facecolor='none',edgecolor='r',linewidth=1.5,zorder=10)

plt.show()
```

==============================

Answer (score 0):

I checked the shapefile that you have uploaded onto the dropbox. It turns out the shapefile is not being read correctly.

when I print out the records for the **MAR_locations_v2.shp**, this is what i get

> Record(MULTIPOLYGON (((386523.5418971451 6432084.711430285, 386523.5418971451
> 6432184.711430287, 386573.541897146 6432184.711430287, 386573.541897146
> 6432084.711430285, 386523.5418971451 6432084.711430285))), {'Name': ''}, )
>
> Record(MULTIPOLYGON (((386405.7078714892 6438043.356735789, 386405.7078714892
> 6438143.356735789, 386505.7078714911 6438143.356735789, 386505.7078714911
> 6438043.356735789, 386405.7078714892 6438043.356735789))), {'Name': ''}, )

and when i print the records for the **AdditionalPumping_south_v2_test.shp**, i get

> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 1, 'row': 465.0, 'column_': 94.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 2, 'row': 469.0, 'column_': 97.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 3, 'row': 470.0, 'column_': 94.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 4, 'row': 473.0, 'column_': 106.0, 'Shape_Leng': 80.0, 'Shape_Area': -400.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 5, 'row': 475.0, 'column_': 93.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 6, 'row': 475.0, 'column_': 97.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 7, 'row': 480.0, 'column_': 93.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 8, 'row': 482.0, 'column_': 97.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 9, 'row': 482.0, 'column_': 110.0, 'Shape_Leng': 80.0, 'Shape_Area': -400.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 10, 'row': 485.0, 'column_': 92.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 11, 'row': 489.0, 'column_': 97.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 12, 'row': 490.0, 'column_': 92.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 13, 'row': 491.0, 'column_': 114.0, 'Shape_Leng': 80.0, 'Shape_Area': -400.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 14, 'row': 495.0, 'column_': 91.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 15, 'row': 496.0, 'column_': 97.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 16, 'row': 500.0, 'column_': 91.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 17, 'row': 500.0, 'column_': 118.0, 'Shape_Leng': 80.0, 'Shape_Area': -400.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 18, 'row': 503.0, 'column_': 97.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 19, 'row': 509.0, 'column_': 120.0, 'Shape_Leng': 80.0, 'Shape_Area': -400.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 20, 'row': 510.0, 'column_': 96.0, 'Shape_Leng': 240.0, 'Shape_Area': -2000.0}, )
>
> Record(GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY, {'OBJECTID': 21, 'row': 518.0, 'column_': 119.0, 'Shape_Leng': 80.0, 'Shape_Area': -400.0}, )

this is not a complete answer to the question, however it answers the part why you are not getting the plot. You might want to save your shapefile differently in order to get it to plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will double check the shape file. If I use ArcMap, the shape file works well. But I agree, there must be something wrong here. Can I ask how you read the shape file? Is it through Python?

Comment: i did a quick validity check on your shapefiles in QGIS before attempting to read it in python. Thereafter, i just checked the output of `shapereader.Reader` which you used with `ax.add_geometries`

Comment: I have tried to save the shapefile to different versions. It doesn't help. I also tried pyshp. It works in pyshp. I guess this is an issue with cartopy.

Comment: If you are able to read the shapefile with pyshp, you can just use the geometry from there and attach it to cartopy. I think cartopy is flexible in that way. I was going to suggest raising this issue on cartopy github page, but it seems you have already raised it.

Answer (score 0):

The Cartopy community on Github has found a solution on this. For anyone who is interested in this, please see https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1217